# Solving an inequality of the form $a\cos(nt) + b\cos(mt) + \cdots > k$

Tags: trigonometry, signal-processing, functional-inequalities

I need to find where sums of a different scaling and frequencies of a given periodic function become greater than a constant. For this example I chose cosine, but if there is a way to solve it for example for square waves, etc please let me know.

$n,~ m,~ \cdots~$ are integers $~a,~b,~\cdots~$ are real and  $~k~$ is a real constant. I need to solve it for $~t~$. The number of terms on the left is finite.

The inequality:

$$a\,\cos(nt)+b\,\cos(mt) + c\,\cos(lt) + \cdots >k$$

If not in the continuous domain, can it be analytically solved in the discrete domain?

Comment: Is this a sum of finitely many terms? Or is this an infinite series?

Comment: Finite. Sorry I should add that as an edit too.